# how to enableJsonFunctions=1 in exasol database?

Tags: exasolution, exasol

I am trying to search for exasol paramter value to enable json functions JSON_EXTRACT , JSON_VALUE etc. My exasol version is 6.2 , But unable to use the functions. Can someone quide me on how to enable it from Database ?
I have checked the values in EXA_METADATA and EXA_PARAMTER sys tables but could not find json parameter name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enableJsonFunctions` is a command line parameter. This means you have to specify it e.g. via EXAoperations (See "Extra DB Parameters" [here](https://docs.exasol.com/administration/on-premise/manage_database/create_db.htm)) and this will require a database restart. Also make sure that you are at least on 6.2.7. Starting from 7.0, the json functions are available without the command line parameter.